Refresh a turbo tag from a job doing broadcasts
I have an app that shows some data to a user through a simple web page. The page contains a text area that shows some logs.
The logs get saved in an active record in a rails job periodically and I want to show all the data to the user by just refreshing the text area. not the whole page. The text area is bound to the active record.
So I get into a loop in the job, I save the data to the active record and I want to have the text area get refreshed. Is there a way to do a partial refresh of the text area that contains the logs?
I read about morphing a turbo frame but how one triggers morphing through Turbo:Channel broadcast?
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/page_refreshes#turbo-frames
For example, in my job I can do this, where {dom_id(message) is my text_area turbo_tag but this is too complicated:
Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_append_to("partial_message",
            target: "#{dom_id(message)}",
            html:   "#{{result.to_s.squish}\n")

Thank you.

there is broadcast_refresh_to
